# remove nested json elements and display as individual key value pairs

Tags: javascript, json

I want to remove the nested json object and show it as key value pairs individually. here is my json object

```
[
  {
    "fileId": 123,
    "fileName": "test file.zip",
    "createdOnDate": "2013-03-22T17:02:00",    
    "valueList": {
      "text_box": "Testing textbox",
      "text_area": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
    }
  }
]
```

how do I format it so the object will look like

```
[
  {
    "fileId": 123,
    "fileName": "test file.zip",
    "createdOnDate": "2013-03-22T17:02:00",    
    "text_box": "Testing textbox",
      "text_area": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"

  }
]
```

using jquery?

Comment: If you want just this specific case changed, @jmar777 has it. If you want something more generic that works in the general case of nested objects, we need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple, but not all encompassing, solution.

```
function unseat(obj, prop) {
    for(var k in obj[prop])
        obj[k] = obj[prop][k];
    delete obj[prop];
    return obj;
}
var testObj =   {
    "fileId": 123,
    "fileName": "test file.zip",
    "createdOnDate": "2013-03-22T17:02:00",    
    "valueList": {
      "text_box": "Testing textbox",
      "text_area": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
    }
  };
testObj = unseat(testObj, "valueList");
for(var k in testObj) 
    console.log(k + " " + testObj[k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
theArray.forEach(function(item) {
    item.text_box = item.valueList.text_box;
    item.text_area = item.valueList.text_area;
    delete item.valueList;
});
```